# MongoDB - Query for date less than returns wrong results

Tags: mongodb, date

While was querying for documents between two dates (the field type is of Date) like -

```
db.getCollection('ledgers').find({
    created: {
        $gt: ISODate("2019-01-19"),
        $lt: ISODate("2019-02-19")
    }
}).sort({'created':-1})
```

It was returning documents for the year 2018 also.

[image: Screenshot for the Result]

Comment: It looks like a timezone issue. The query is ok

Comment: Actually the results are ok and it has nothing to do with timezones. Look closely the result is from `2019-02-18` which is actually lower than `2019-02-19`

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores times, not dates. You need to convert your dates to times in your application and query by time ranges.

Answer (score 0):

The date on your post [https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIWhf.png] is 2019-02-18 which is in the range you specified in your query.

I suggest you either provide an example of the error at https://mongoplayground.net/

or correct/delete the question itslef.

Thanks